# How to set a vector point on an exact lat/long coordinate

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have a vector polygon I'm trying to edit, I'd like to use exact lat/long coordinates for one of the vector points. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activate the Vertex Editor tool (Digitizing toolbar)

[image]

Right-click on your feature. This brings up a menu with one option: Vertex editor. Click on Vertex Editor to open the Vertex Editor panel. Here you can edit vertices by typing coordinates.

[image]

The coordinate system depends on the CRS of your layer. If your layer is in a meter-based projection system, the coordinates will be in meters. If your layer is in a latitude/longitude based system, the coordinates will be in lat/long.

Comment: Can't believe it was so easy

Comment: I believe this is relatively new as a core feature.